# adjustPan: set the view to pan to

Tags: android

I have a popup that has a multi-line edit text and can appear at arbitrary position atop my application. Currently I have implemented it as a transparent activity. When the keyboard is shown over the popup, it jumps up and the current line is shown above the keyboard (I have the `adjustPan` flag set).

Now, I want the whole popup to go up and show above the keyboard, not only one line of text box. I was able to achieve this by moving focus to the whole layout when the EditText is focused, but then, well, the EditText loses focus, and I cannot type. Is there any other way way to do this? Or is there a way to focus a view without losing focus on another?